# How can I find what time of day it is in python?

Tags: python, time

what time of day is it ? [morning/afternoon/evening/night]

```
#example:
a = day()
print("The time is ") + a
```

Should Output

```
The time is Morning/evening/afternoon/night
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda easy!

Code:

```py
import datetime as dt

def day(han):       #find what time of day is it?
    t = han.datetime.now()
    h = t.strftime("%H")
    h = int(h)
    if h < 12:
        return "morning"
        h = 0
        t = 0
    if h < 16:
        return "afternoon"
        h = 0
        t = 0
    if h < 19:
        return "evening"
        h = 0
        t = 0
    if h < 24:
        return "night"
        h = 0
        t = 0
    return "midnight"
    h = 0
    t = 0

a = day(dt)
print("The time is " + dt)
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! thanx

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `datetime` module for that

```py
from datetime import datetime

def get_time_of_day(time):
    if time < 12:
        return "Morning"
    elif time < 16:
        return "Afternoon"
    elif time < 19:
        return "Evening"
    else:
        return "Night"



now = datetime.now()
print("It's currently:", get_time_of_day(now.hour))
```